# How to unit test with a dependency on MFMailComposeViewController and it's class method?

Tags: ios, swift, unit-testing, mocking

Using Swift, I'm attempting to unit test the following class used in an iOS app.  The class displays either an MFMailComposeViewController if the user has their system Mail app setup or an alert view if no system Mail is setup.  I don't know the best way to test it.

I'm not sure how to simply add an MFMailComposeViewController variable to the class and then pass in a mock object because (1) I need MFMailComposeViewController's class method canSendMail() and (2) I'd rather the instance of MFMailComposeViewController not persist after it is displayed and dismissed.

What is the best way to test this class?  Does it need to be redesigned?

```
public class EmailAction:NSObject, MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate {

public var name:String
public weak var displayingViewController:UIViewController?
public var email:String
public var subject:String

public init(name:String, email:String, subject:String) {
    self.name = name
    self.email = email
    self.subject = subject
}

@objc public func showEmailComposeViewController() {
    if MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail() {
        let mailVC = MFMailComposeViewController()
        mailVC.mailComposeDelegate = self
        mailVC.setToRecipients([email])
        mailVC.setSubject(subject)
        displayingViewController?.present(mailVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    } else {
        let noMailAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Email Not Setup", message: "Setup an email account on this device's Mail app to be able to send mail from this app", preferredStyle: .alert)
        let okButton = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil)
        noMailAlert.addAction(okButton)
        displayingViewController?.present(noMailAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

public func mailComposeController(_ controller: MFMailComposeViewController, didFinishWith result: MFMailComposeResult, error: Error?) {
    displayingViewController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

}

Comment: Isn't this a case for UI Tests, not Unit Tests?

Comment: @user3581248 I don't think so, but I'm not sure.  I just want to test that this class presents an MFMailComposeViewController when canSendMail() returns true and displays an alert when that method returns false.  I think that's more suitable for unit tests, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would create a protocol that has all the methods I need of `MFMailComposeViewController`:

```
@objc protocol MailComposeViewController {
    init()
    class func canSendMail() -> Bool
    func setSubject(_: String)
    //... and others
}
```

I would extend `MFMailComposeViewController` to conform:

```
extension MFMailComposeViewController: MailComposeViewController {}
```

And then I would add a class of type `MailComposeViewController` as a dependency of `EmailAction`. From there, I could provide `MFMailComposeViewController` as the usual implementation, but I could also provide a mock for testing.

Comment: I understand this strategy, but there are two issues:  
The main one is I'm not sure how to call the class method on the MailComposeViewController mock since the instance is being passed in.  
Also I'd rather the MFMailComposeViewController not persist after it is dismissed but rather get created whenever showEmailComposeViewController() is called.

Comment: `since the instance is being passed in`? `Also I'd rather the MFMailComposeViewController not persist` That's why I said this: `I would add a class of type MailComposeViewController as a dependency of EmailAction` ***class***, not *instance*. You keep the class (of type `MailComposeViewController`) as a dependency, and since it has an `init` method defined, you can instantiate it in `showEmailComposeViewController`, whenever you need it.

Comment: So this would be added to EmailAction? 
`public var mailComposeClass:MailComposeViewController.Type`

Comment: @GingerBreadMane I can test it myself right now, but yeah, something like that

Comment: Ok. Interesting. This strategy creates a protocol that both MFMailComposeViewController and The MockMailViewController will conform to.  What if, instead, the protocol didn't exist and the dependency of EmailAction was a class of type MFMailComposeViewController?  Then the mock is a subclass of MFMailComposeViewController?  Is the protocol better than this in some way?

Comment: I prefer mocking via a new type that conforms to a common protocol over subclassing. There's a lot of classes that can't be subclassed, contain ivars/properties I don't need, or have initializers a mock couldn't satisfy. YMMV

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149041/discussion-between-alexander-and-gingerbreadmane).

Comment: @Alexander the all sounds good but how would inject `MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail()` call?

Comment: You just never reference `MFMailComposeViewController` directly. You reference a `MailComposeViewController` variable (e.g. a singleton), and call `canSendMail()` on it. Either the mock implementation or the real implementation will respond.